# Alternating between two css animations with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a kind pendulum system with 3 balls. I've already create the balls and methods to animate them. Here's my code:

```css
.circle {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.circle_container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  margin-top:07%;
}

.circle:first-child {
  animation: translate1 2s ease-in-out 0s 1 normal; 
}

.circle:last-child {
  animation: translate2 2s ease-in-out 2s 1 normal ; 
}

@keyframes translate1 {
  0% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
  50% {
     transform : translateX(-60px) translateY(-25px);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
}

@keyframes translate2 {
  0% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
  50% {
     transform : translateX(60px) translateY(-25px);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">
  <div class="circle" id="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

This example show in a cycle what I want to realize. But the problem is that it only occurs one time. I want to make it switch like this indefinitely.

When I replace 1 by infinite on the animation-iteration-count property the two animations play in a different way.

So, how can I use jquery to make the balls move like in my demo indefinitely (with the same alternation, the first ball move left-right then the third goes right-left and so on)... Please if someone have an idea on how using jquery to fix this i'm ready to receive their advice.

Comment: Your easing looks unnatural. The balls slow down on the down-swing when they should be accelerating.

Answer (score 2):

No need to use jQuery, you would just need a delay at the beginning of the second animation and at the end of the first:

```css
.circle {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background-color:#000;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.circle_container {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  margin-top:07%;
}

.circle:first-child {
  animation: translate1 4s ease-in-out infinite;  /* 4s is for a 2s animation as 50% of the time it is not doing anything */
}

.circle:last-child {
  animation: translate2 4s ease-in-out infinite; 
}

@keyframes translate1 {
  0% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
  25% {
     transform : translateX(-60px) translateY(-25px);
  }
  
  50% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);  /* only animate to 50% so the last 50% is doing nothing - this is when animation 2 runs */
  }
  
  100% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
}

@keyframes translate2 {
  0% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px); /* don't animate first 50% - this is when animation 1 runs */
  }
  50% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
  75% {
     transform : translateX(60px) translateY(-25px);
  }
  
  100% {
    transform : translateX(0px) translateY(0px);
  }
  
}
```

```html
<div class="circle_container">
  <div class="circle" id="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks Pete, i'm not a native english speaker i'm trying to learn.